# Which inner tube do I need to buy for 28 inch fixie bike?

Tags: tire, innertube, inflation, tyre-width

I have a 2018 FIXIE Inc. Betty Leeds.

[image]

https://www.fahrrad.de/fixie-inc-betty-leeds-white-694674.html

These are the sizes of the tyres:

*Reifen vorne Marke: Kenda Typ: K-193 Größe: 28 Zoll Reifenbreite: 28 mm*

(Tire front Brand: Kenda Type: K-193 Size: 28 inches Tire width: 28 mm)

and I am looking for inner-tubes here:
https://www.bike-discount.de/

Unfortunately, I did not see the description of the inner-tyres in the web-site.
Which one should I buy?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

All you need to know the wheel rim diameter, tire width, valve type and valve length.

Google translate to English of what's written on you tire is:

> Tire front Brand: Kenda Type: K-193 Size: 28 inches Tire width: 28 mm

`28 inches` refers to the wheel diameter. This means a rim with a rim tire bead seat diameter of 622mm, also known as *700c* (and *29 inches* for mountain bikes).

`Tire width: 28 mm` means, well, the tire is 28mm wide. Typically tubes have a minimum and maximum tire width they will support.

See [here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts/284#284) and [here](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/244/terminology-index-a-list-of-bike-part-names-and-cycling-concepts/283#283) for determining what valve type you have.

You need valves long enough to reach through the rim with at least a couple of centimeters protruding.

Comment: Thanks! So all of the tires here are ok - https://www.bike-discount.de/en/search?q=700+c+28+mm ? They are all 600c/28mm

Comment: I think you mean *tubes* not *tires*. Not all of them are the right size. The Vittoria ones have a description like this `700x25/32C` 25 means the min width, 32 means the max. You want one with min<=28<=max. I.e. `700x25/32C` is good, `700x33/37C` is too big.

Comment: Yes, I mean tubes. There are 2 with `700x25/32C`. (Vittoria Lite Inner Tube 28" 700x25/32C AV 48mm)[https://www.bike-discount.de/en/buy/vittoria-lite-inner-tube-28-700x25-32c-av-48mm-568645] and [Vittoria Lite Inner Tube 28" 700x25/32C DV 40mm
](https://www.bike-discount.de/en/buy/vittoria-lite-inner-tube-28-700x25-32c-dv-40mm-568661)

Comment: I forgot to mention valve length - which is what the 40mm and 48mm specs are. Your rims do not look very deep so 40mm should be fine.

Comment: Super, thanks! Will buy these ones and will try to install them on Sunday - **Lite Inner Tube 28" 700x25/32C DV 40mm**

Comment: FYI, specific shopping advice is technically off topic on this site. I wrote a generic answer, and I don't mind providing more help through comments. There may be votes to close your question as duplicate as I'm sure there are other similar ones already.

Comment: I guess you are right. That's why I tried to make it really as general as I could. Feel free to edit the question, avoiding the sites if you feel like it, thus it would be able to help more people. :) Still, once more, thank you! Let's see whether it would be ok on Sunday.

Comment: The ventil was too big, did not fit. :(